# how to call a value from array in AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
$scope.persons = [{name:'Joey', age:'27'}]
```

I can call the value in HTML in this way

```
{{person.name}}
```

But when I try something like this, it fails

```
$scope.name = $routeParams.person.name
```

I could read the person only (without .name), it will be displayed as an array.But I want to access to the name key. Thx in advance.

I pass the person to JS in this way (route)

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="person in persons">         
    <td headers="more">
        <a href="#details/{{person}}}">Show Details</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try this $scope.persons[0].name

Comment: What does `$routeParams.person` look like? an object? an array?

Comment: I don't need to do persons[0], because I have get an object in persons

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, as you are accessing value from array, whenever you access value from array need to mention index.

```
$scope.name = $routeParams.persons[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<a href="#details/{{person.name}}/{{person.age}}">Show Details</a>
```

Comment: I did this way before, but my tutor suggested me to pass the 'person'. And thanks let know I have an extra }

Comment: @JoeyZhang you can't pass the person object directly

Comment: Is it means if I pass a person, the 'person' I got is actually a string?